# Discount is shown, after browser refresh / cart update / during checkout not shown anymore

Tags: commerce

I have added a few simple discounts like all products from a certain brand (category) get a 10% product discount. My discounts are shown/calculated fine 70% of the time, but 30% of the time (or even more) they are NOT calculated. When I refresh my browser, they aren't calculated, when I refresh again they are calculated. It's like toggling between discount and no discount just by refreshing the browser (cmd+r).

But the most bizar thing I see in my shopping cart. I use the normal view with a few lay-out changes. My product is the field (Line items referenced by commerce_line_items) Commerce Line item: Product (Product) - Formatter: rendered product, View mode: Line item. I added the price to the Line item display, just for debugging.
Prices are shown as Formatted amount with savings.

Normal view:
Discount is calculated on the price per item and the total product price, but not on my rendered product display (with the image)
[image: Shoppingcart view (with discount)]

After refresh or status update or next time you go to your shoppingcart (or during checkout)
Discount is NOT calculated on the price per item and the total product price, so the user does not get the discount price, but not on my rendered product display (with the image) the discount is calculated !!
[image: Shoppingcart view (without discount)]

When the discount is calculated in my shoppingcart and I go to checkout, the discount isn't calculated anymore in the order review . Or the other way round.

What is happening here ? How can I fix this ? Is this a bug somewhere? I have a few stores with commerce kickstart, never had this problem. This is the first store without Kickstart. If I compare my views, displays, modules and more with my other stores, I can't find a difference.
I don't have any errors in dblog,

I did not change anything to the price calculation rule.

I use normal Drupal Commerce, not Kickstart

- Commerce Discount 7.x-1.0-alpha7 + Commerce Discount Date + Commerce Discount Usage
- Commerce Discount Product Category 7.x-1.2
- Commerce Price Savings Formatter 7.x-1.4

Comment: Are you using any discount compatibility settings (can't remember if they were in alpha7) or coupons on the site?

Comment: No coupons, no dates, no usage, ... nothing special. Only the Product Category to add product discount for products with a certain taxonomy term